# Why this SimpleDateFormat lost info about time?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have this Java method that process a ResultSet.

```
protected void populateDto(String[] rowSet, ResultSet rs, String[] columunsNames) throws SQLException {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSet.length; i++) {
        rowSet[i] = rs.getString(columunsNames[i]);
    }
}
```

As you can see all result are treated as String type (getString is used whatever is the column type). When a Date column is encountered it is automatically converted into a String. The resulting date will appear similar to this one:

> 2012-08-01 16:10:47.0

I have modified the above script, creating something like that:

```
protected void populateDto(String[] rowSet, ResultSet rs, String[] columunsNames) throws SQLException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSet.length; i++) {
        Object o = rs.getObject(columunsNames[i]);
        if (o instanceof Date) {
            rowSet[i] = formatter.format((Date)o);
        } else {
            rowSet[i] = (String)o;
        }   
    }
}
```

This method treat everything as Object, after, will check if that Object is an instance of Date. If this is true it will formatted in according to the `formatter`. The problem is that in this way the data returned is like:

> 2012-08-01 00:00:00.0

Why?

**Update 1 - Last working method implementation:**

```
protected void populateDto(String[] rowSet, ResultSet rs, String[] columunsNames, SimpleDateFormat formatter) throws SQLException {
    Timestamp ts = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSet.length; i++) {
        Object obj = rs.getObject(columunsNames[i]);
        if (obj instanceof Date) {
            ts = rs.getTimestamp(columunsNames[i]);
            rowSet[i] = formatter.format(ts);
        } else {
            if(obj!=null)
                rowSet[i] = obj+"";
            else
                rowSet[i] = "";
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This method treat everything as Object, after, will check if that Object is an instance of Date.*

Instead of `date` use `java.sql.Timestamp`, with this you can get Date as well as Time either you persist data or fetch data.

*Update 1*

You can have a general method like

```
public Timestamp getTimestamp(int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    Object value = getObject(columnIndex);
    if (value instanceof Timestamp) return (Timestamp) value;

  }
```

this will return the date and time and you could call by passing the column index.

Comment: If I check for instanceof Timestamp i get an error as well as I cast object into Timestamp. What should I do?

Comment: Where do u suggest to use Timestamp? How should u modify my method?

Comment: @Mariano You could get the value by `rowSet[i] = rs.getTimestamp(columunsNames[i]);` You do need SimpleDateFormat anymore as you do need to format any date and time unless it is required for any other purpose.

Comment: I've used java.sql.Date as second member of instanceof. Final method is appended to original answer. ;)

Comment: @Mariano You still use SimpleDateFormat? And instead of Date you could use Timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

[`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) does not store info about time:

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.